# Why does this piece of code increment? C#

Tags: c#, arrays, increment, recording, bin

Thanks for looking at this page. I'm new to C# and I would like to know why this piece of code increments the values. Essentially, I am looking to measure the velocity of individual particles in a system, however, the results from the text file shows that each value of velocity adds to the next. What I need is to put a count of each value for velocity into a bin, for example a count of 1 for velocities between 0 and 0.5 go into bin 1 and 0.5 to 1.0 into bin 2 and so on, so then the values of each bin can be written into a text file which I could then turn into a histogram to see how often each velocity in a certain bin occurs. My piece of code is below. I am very grateful for any help which I am given. Thank you for looking at the page.

```
private void computeVelocity()
    {
        //calc velocity of each particle for printing
        double binSize = 0.5;
        double velocityOfParticle = 0.0;
        double averageSquareVelocity = 0.0;
        int maxArrayValue = 0;
        int binArraySize = 0;
        int z;
        double[] velocityArray = new double[Particle.allParticles.Count];

        for (int counter = 0; counter < Particle.allParticles.Count; counter++)
        {
            averageSquareVelocity = Particle.allParticles[counter].SquareVelocity;
            velocityOfParticle = Math.Sqrt(averageSquareVelocity);
            velocityArray[counter] = velocityOfParticle; 
        }
        maxArrayValue = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(velocityArray.Max()));
        binArraySize = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(maxArrayValue / binSize));
        //numberOfBins = Math.Round(maxArrayValue / binSize);
        int [] binCountArray = new int[numberOfParticles];
        int incrementTerm = 0;
        Array.Clear(binCountArray, 0, binCountArray.Length);
        for(double counter = 0.0; counter <= maxArrayValue; counter = counter + binSize)
        {
            if(counter > binSize)
            {
                incrementTerm = incrementTerm + 1;
            }
            z = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < numberOfParticles; i++)
            {
                if(velocityArray[i] <= counter)
                {
                    z++;
                }                  
            }     
            binCountArray[incrementTerm] = z;
        }
        foreach (var item in binCountArray)
        {
            VelocityValues.WriteLine(item);
        }
      }
```

Comment: Because of the Math.Round syntax.

Comment: What's the problem?  Your title says it increments, and your description describes how you want incrementing bins to count frequency of each velocity group.  There is no problem definition here.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(velocityArray[i] <= counter)
```

This will add everything under counter, instead of under counter and over counter-binSize.  Corrected (probably):

```
private void computeVelocity()
    {
        //calc velocity of each particle for printing
        double binSize = 0.5;
        double velocityOfParticle = 0.0;
        double averageSquareVelocity = 0.0;
        int maxArrayValue = 0;
        int binArraySize = 0;
        int z;
        double[] velocityArray = new double[Particle.allParticles.Count];

        for (int counter = 0; counter < Particle.allParticles.Count; counter++)
        {
            averageSquareVelocity = Particle.allParticles[counter].SquareVelocity;
            velocityOfParticle = Math.Sqrt(averageSquareVelocity);
            velocityArray[counter] = velocityOfParticle; 
        }
        maxArrayValue = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(velocityArray.Max()));
        binArraySize = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(maxArrayValue / binSize));
        //numberOfBins = Math.Round(maxArrayValue / binSize);
        int [] binCountArray = new int[numberOfParticles];
        int incrementTerm = 0;
        Array.Clear(binCountArray, 0, binCountArray.Length);
        for(double counter = 0.0; counter <= maxArrayValue; counter = counter + binSize)
        {
            if(counter > binSize)
            {
                incrementTerm = incrementTerm + 1;
            }
            z = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < numberOfParticles; i++)
            {
                if((velocityArray[i] <= counter) && (velocityArray[i] > counter - binSize))
                {
                    z++;
                }                  
            }     
            binCountArray[incrementTerm] = z;
        }
        foreach (var item in binCountArray)
        {
            VelocityValues.WriteLine(item);
        }
      }
```